# SVN Forced remote commit

Tags: svn, automation

We are having distributed team, even after trying to follow practices many developers forget to commit during closing hours. Is it possible to have some way from server itself we can auto commit all files in particular folder branch at time from all clients. So even if developer(s) forgets to commit we can get the latest.

Comment: I think you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758916/how-to-make-subversion-or-any-program-perform-periodic-commits

Comment: How would you know that uncommitted changes are ready to be committed?

Comment: Of course this operation can break the build and it is a very bad idea, but the upper link is actually the solution. Here I would suggest better training for the developers.

Comment: Sorry if any one gets confuses in terms of worrying point of builds or quality. We already have separate repositories and arrangements for it. So that is not point. My main question is still is there any way to have some way that can make auto commit the code remotely ? Beside this I am also seeing one advantage to have facility also provided to network admins for any hardware updates. Its bad if he needs to go and check on individual developers machine whether everything is commited or not. Here even if its code is committed in error mode we dont have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everybody is running Windows then schedule a task at the required time that will run a batch file which simply does this:

`svn ci -m "<your default commit message to indicate that this is an automatic commit done by the scheduled task>"`

If it is a *nix environment then setup a `cron` job.